# split() function skips blanks

Tags: google-sheets

In `A1` cell I have `A,B,C,,E`. I want to split the cell into five cells: `A` , `B`, `C`, , `E`

This formula `=split(A1,",")` splits into four cells `A`, `B`, `C`, `E` and skips over the blank.

How do I tell it to split "properly"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can specify that directly, though here is a workaround:

1. Add another delimiter character to your string. So replace `,` with say `,|`
2. Now when you split with `,`, we know for sure that even empty columns will have a character (in this case `|`)
3. Use replace to substitute the extra delimiter `|` with a blank string
4. Since output of `split` is an array, you will need to use [`arrayformula`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/71291?hl=en)

Here is what the final formula would look like

```
=arrayformula(substitute(split(substitute(A1,",",",|"),","), "|",""))
```

Comment: problem with that is A4 is dynamic, you don't know where you are getting a blank

Comment: that won't effect this logic. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Let me clarify. What if you don't know `A4` is blank. What if `A2` was blank? Need some more general

Comment: my bad, i should have used the reference `A1`. So what I meant was instead of your `=split(A1)`, you could use `=arrayformula(substitute(split(substitute(A1,",",",|"),","), "|",""))`. Initially I had used `A4` instead of `A1` in my formula. I edited my solution

Comment: For reference https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ezh9mIj-ajKw6AI3ezQEx9fa3a91Ps1KGPiFuhRhDB8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

If you use FALSE as the fourth argument, it will work as expected.
Try using

```
=SPLIT(A2,",", TRUE, FALSE)
```

and you won't need to do work arounds

[image: the output for above formula]

Answer (score 2):

For a workaround I have an alternative suggestion: Replace `,,` with `, ,` prior to =split.

However the 'proper' way is probably is to override the default [remove_empty_text](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) parameter:

```
=split(A1,",",,)
```

Comment: That sounds problematic, because instead of blank cells you get cells that appear blank but in fact contain a single space. This is likely to come back and bite someone later.

Comment: It would be safer to replace all `,,` with `,-,` instead of `, ,`. But anyway this would not work as expected if there are i.e. 2 empty values in a row. Example: you might expect that `=substitute  (  "1,,,4"  ;  ",,"  ;  ",-,"  )` will return `1,-,-,4`, but it actually returns `1,-,,4`.

Comment: yeah... I found out that you need to run a couple of passes for this logic... but It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to skip the `SPLIT` function and apply *Split text into columns...* instead (under Data). This will leave D1 of length `0`.